# Will a parent object no more accessible from a GC root thread be elligible for Java GC even if one of its child is referenced by the root thread?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-11

Let's say we have the following classes

```
public class Parent {
  
  public Child child;

  public Parent(Child child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
}

public class Child {

  public String someField;
}
```

And we have the following code in our main

```
Parent parent = new Parent(new Child());
Child child = parent.child;
parent = null;
// then do other stuff
```

Will the parent be elligible for garbage collection after setting it to null even if one of its internal field / child is directly referenced by the main root thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be eligible for GC, because `Child` has no reference to `Parent`, leaving no references to the `Parent` object when its variable is set to null. Note: this can be demoed by invoking System.gc() (for testing purposes), and overriding the finalize() method in Parent and Child. The method will be invoked on the object when the JVM determines that it's ready for GC.

Comment: And `Child` will not be elligible since root has a direct reference to it, correct ?

Comment: @Jeep87c Yes indeed. BTW you can verify this by invoking `System.gc()` (don't do it in production), and overriding the `finalize()` method in `Parent` and `Child`. The method will be invoked when the JVM determines that it's ready for GC.